# Función alternativa al método __getitem__ u operador []

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, index, getitem

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna función alternativa para acceder a los elementos de un *indexable* (`Sequence` o `Mapping`), aparte del método `__getitem__` y el operador `[]`.

Necesito obtener una función a la cual se la pueda pasar por argumento cualquier *indexable* y devuelva el elemento de una posición concreta fijada. La manera que había pensado en implementarlo era usando una función `lambda`:

```py
f = lambda indexable: indexable["clave"]
```

o crear directamente una función:

```py
def f(indexable):
    return indexable["clave"]
```

Se usa `clave` como ejemplo de literal inmutable para acceder a una posición, pero, si el objeto *indexable* pasado a la función es una *secuencia*, la clave debe de ser un número entero o un *slice* (mismas restricciones que al usar `__getitem__` or `[]`).

Tras crear la función, podría llamar a `f()` pasando como argumento cualquier *indexable* y me devolvería su valor en la posición `clave`.

**¿Existe alguna forma de obtener esta misma función sin recurrir a `lambda` o `def`?**

Comment: Por aclarar un poco: _Iterable_ es cualquier objeto que devuelve sus elementos de uno en uno. Si quieres obtener un elemento, tendrás que pasar secuencialmente por todos los elementos hasta llegar al que pides. ¿Es eso lo que pides? El ejemplo que pones es más un diccionario (objeto _Mapping_).

Comment: @ChemaCortes, sí, a lo que me refería es a un objeto indexable. Puse la pregunta también en stackoverflow en inglés y me la han cerrado al momento por ello. Ya lo he modificado en la pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Posible solución: `operator.itemgetter` => https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter

Answer (score 1):

No dices qué problema ves con la expresión *lambada* o la función para buscar alternativas.

Python es un *lenguaje dinámico* por lo que no chequea el tipo del argumento que pasas a una función, ya sea un diccionario (*Mapping*) o una secuencia (*Sequence*). Puedes usar la misma función en ambos casos.

Si por algún motivo no quieres tener que hacer tu propia función, también puedes usar el [operador `itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) que te recomienda @carlos-a-gómez:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter("clave")
```

Comment: Se puede usar *diccionario* o *secuencia* en esas funciones. Si se usa como clave un literal que no sea un número entero o un *slice* para acceder a un elemento del *indexable* (no *secuencia*), saltará una excepción `TypeError`, que deberá ser manejada por quien usa esta función y tenido en cuenta; lo mismo ocurre con `__getittem__` y '`[]`.
Necesitaba una función q haga lo mismo q `__getitem__` pero solo pasando como argumento el *indexable*, estando la clave ya prefijada dentro de la función.
Sí, es `operator.itemgetter` justo lo q buscaba. Muchas gracias por ponerlo en una respuesta.

Comment: Ya te decía que python es un lenguaje dinámico. No puedes saber de qué tipo será el argumento hasta el momento de ejecución. Puedes chequear el tipo de dato antes de pasarlo a `__getitem__`, pero en python se sigue la filosofía de _"let it crash"_ y dejar que sea el contexto quién decida si debe interceptar o no los errores de tipo. Todo depende del control que tengas sobre los argumentos que va a utilizar tu función.